# AWS RDS snapshot by Java Code Example

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services, lambda, snapshot

I have an RDS PostgreSQL Instance. Inside the instance I have Databases and tables. Daily I need to update my db through lambda java function. I am done this and works fine. But before updating my table from my lambda java function I need to take a snapshot of the RDS PostgreSQL instance from my lamnda java code. Is it possible? Please direct me to write the code for the same?

Comment: did you try [`createDBSnapshot()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/rds/AmazonRDS.html#createDBSnapshot-com.amazonaws.services.rds.model.CreateDBSnapshotRequest-)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Comment: I tried but I am getting errors. I used below code                                                    CreateDBSnapshotRequest snapShotrequest = new CreateDBSnapshotRequest().withDBSnapshotIdentifier("new-db-snapshot").withDBInstanceIdentifier("mydb");
         DBSnapshot snapShotresponse = rdsclient.createDBSnapshot(snapShotrequest);
         System.out.println(snapShotresponse);

Comment: @Sharon Ben Asher yeh.. it was prfectly right. I give rds accesspermission to my role and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a snapshot of the RDS PostgreSQL instance from my lamnda java code is like below. First you have to give a permission for creating snapshot to your IAM Role.

Go to IAM Management Console --> Roles --> Select your role and add permission 'RDS-access-for-creating-snapshot'.

After giving permission use below code to perform snapshot creation.

```
CreateDBSnapshotRequest snapShotrequest = new CreateDBSnapshotRequest().withDBSnapshotIdentifier("new-snapshotname-"+System.currentTimeMillis()).withDBInstanceIdentifier("currentdbidentifier");
DBSnapshot snapShotresponse = rdsclient.createDBSnapshot(snapShotrequest);
System.out.println("SnapShot Created Successfully");
```